# Parts of post data lost when using org.apache.http library

Tags: android, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm having some issues with incomplete post data being received by our server. This only occurs for a few users of our app. Still not sure which versions of Android we are talking about, but will try to recover that information as soon as possible. 
For the time being: maybe there is someone who also experienced similar problems? It occurs only for our textarea field where users can type large custom texts. There is no filter whatsoever on this field, and will be sent as StringBody to our server directly. The code below is the relevant parts. My concern is the part where the StringBody is created. Is this sufficient for escaping the text properly to not interfere with the post headers?

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
for(int j=0; j<fields.length; j++){
    String value = mydata.get(fields[j]);
    entity.addPart(fields[j], new StringBody(value, "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
}

(..) //some files are added too later on

entity.addPart(image.get("hash"), new FileBody(imageFile));

(..) //and sending the data to the server
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
if(entity != null)
    post.setEntity(entity);

final HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpParams params = http.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 30000);
ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, 30000);

HttpResponse response = http.execute(post);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
if(statusLine.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK){
    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
}

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
out.close();
String result = out.toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this problem. The problem was not in the frontend but in the backend. People were posting [unicode emoticons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticon#unicode) . The backend was built with an MySQL utf8_general_ci collation table/column. This collation does not support the unicode characters and will break the text before the unicode character. So the resulting insert will have all text missing after the unicode character.